# How to fetch data after a specific (primary) key value in Oracle?

Tags: python, database, oracle, fetch

I am working on on the following code. I believe there might be a query to do this.

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(database_host, database_port, database_service)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(database_username, database_password, dsn_tns, cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
print("Database connected")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM " + database_table)
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

Anyone any idea for improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE pk >= some_value;
```

Primary keys on tables are backed up by indexes, so the searching and filtering job specified in that WHERE clause is efficient. The database finds the first row that satisfies the condition, then reads the rest of the rows sequentially. It's called an *index range scan.*

**Pro tip:** Avoid `SELECT *` and instead use `SELECT col, col2, col3`, giving the names of your table's columns you actually need. It saves work on your database server, and makes your queries more resilient to possible future changes in your table.